# Same data but not equal inside two Nodes

Tags: c, string-comparison

When I compare the data inside two Nodes it says that they are not equal, but they print the same info.

```
while(currentUserTry != NULL && currentPassword != NULL) {

    if(currentUserTry->color != currentPassword->color){
        printf("user %s - %lu\n", currentUserTry->color, strlen(currentUserTry->color));
        printf("pass %s - %lu\n", currentPassword->color, strlen(currentPassword->color));
    }

    currentUserTry = currentUserTry->next;
    currentPassword = currentPassword->next;
}
```

prints:
 
user az - 2
pass az - w
user vm - 2
pass vm - 2

Comment: By the way, let us know if what is proposed in the answers works by ticking as accepted, answer. If nothing works, please comment on the answers below on what didn't work and what should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcmp` when comparing two strings.

```
while(currentUserTry != NULL && currentPassword != NULL) {

    if(strcmp(currentUserTry->color, currentPassword->color)){
        printf("user %s - %lu\n", currentUserTry->color, strlen(currentUserTry->color));
        printf("pass %s - %lu\n", currentPassword->color, strlen(currentPassword->color));
    }

    currentUserTry = currentUserTry->next;
    currentPassword = currentPassword->next;
}
```

> The C library function int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2) compares the string pointed to, by str1 to the string pointed to by str2.
>
> This function return values that are as follows:
>
> if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.
>
> if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.
>
> if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.

Answer (score 0):

In this if statement you have to use standard C function strcmp

```
if( strcmp( currentUserTry->color, currentPassword->color ) != 0 ){
```